# MongoDB upgrade and inconsistent integer storage with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, pecl

Since upgrading to MongoDB 2.2 and the version 1.3 PECL package for Mongo (not sure which change is relevant), I've noticed that inserts through PHP for fields cast to ints are now inserted as NumberLong in our collections ( {"userid" : NumberLong(792)} ). Previously, they were inserted as integers( {"userid" : 792} ). And, while new records use NumberLong now, our collections are now mixed, with like fields having unlike types.

Is this likely to cause problems, particularly with indexing and finding? Is one format preferred (I assume NumberLong is preferred)? Is there a straightforward way to update our collections to the new format, assuming that is a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purposes of querying, you should not have any problem with numeric fields of varying types. Integers, longs, and doubles all undergo conversion before being compared. Likewise, if you had a unique index on some numeric field `x`, you would receive an error attempting to insert two documents with values `1` and `1.0` for `x`. This is mentioned in the [Compare Order for BSON Types](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#what-is-the-compare-order-for-bson-types) documentation.

Comment: However, that page also says: "Storing values of the different types in the same field in a collection is strongly discouraged."

Comment: While there are caveats to varying numeric types in the same field, I imagine that warning was referring to truly incomparable types (e.g. strings and objects). That said, it would be trivial to query your collection for all fields of an appropriate type (using the `$type` operator) and then manually updating the values to the desired numeric type to make things consistent across the board.

Answer (score -1):

I have rewritten this answer because I wrote it quickly last night and haven't really looked at it since.

This is because the ini setting for `native_long` has been set to on

> The MongoDB data type that is used in this case is the BSON LONG, instead of the BSON INT that is used if this setting is turned off.

http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.configuration.php#ini.mongo.native-long

The rationale behind this is to allow 64bit system to store 64bit INTs.

As advised on the Doc page:

> The default behavior for this will be changed to TRUE in 2.0.0, so make sure to set this variable to the value you want (probably TRUE) so that the driver's behavior doesn't suddenly change when you upgrade.

So it could be a good idea to upgrade all your documents and ensure that they are compatible with this future feature of the driver.

So to answer:

> Is there a straightforward way to update our collections to the new format, assuming that is a good idea?

No there isn't really. You would need to go through all your documents and resave them with the right data types.

As for some of your concerns:

> Is this likely to cause problems, particularly with indexing and finding? Is one format preferred (I assume NumberLong is preferred)?

It is a different object so it will cause problems with finding by these numbers.

However if you setup your PHP application to handle this bit the driver will automatically convert INTs for you into their respective representation in the database. So once setup it does not really create any extra work since on the PHP end you will just see the normal `int` object type.

As for indexing, it shouldn't effect that much. Only the value is stored in the index and the value is the same between the two here.

If you run into problems using this feature at the moment you can always turn it off from your PHP.ini by commenting out the line in there that actually turns this on.

Comment: This is not correct as native_long is *not* on by default in 1.3.x. We will do this for driver version 2.x at the earliest.

Comment: @Derick Ah yea I misread the text at the top, sorry about that

Comment: @Derick Hopefully that rewrite should do it, that'll teach me for writing quicker than I can think

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Our native_long ini setting is TRUE on 1.3.3, and I don't think we've changed it from the default. You also say that because we are storing a different object, it will cause problems finding by those numbers; I find that if you search for NumberLong(12345), you get results with both types of data, and vice versa, of you search for {'number':12345}. It seems that data returned to PHP from the format {'number':12345} returns as a float, while NumberLongs return as ints--that is concerning, although not necessarily a problem. So I'm still not sure what to do here.

Comment: @Karptonite Ha I must admit that part I didn't test but I know that MongoDB itself will not help here so possibly the driver does two versions of the field in the query, I will have to test this further and look into the source code unless Derick replies about that. Yes numberLong converts to int, when you input a normal float it will save as a float, as you said it ain't much of a problem you should be casting all your input values anyway.

Comment: @Karptonite If you are deadly certain you didn't change the defaults at all and only downloaded the driver you may wish to file a jira: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP for it. As for what to do; it depends on whether you store 64bit ints at anytime? If not then you can probably turn it off however as I said it will be on by default by 2.0 of the driver (at the earliest)  and it doesn't really add weight so I personally have just worked it into my app.

Comment: I have been casting all of my input integers to (int) all along--otherwise, they would be saved as strings. It is now the case that numbers in that format return from mongo through the PECL package as floats. My test showing that I got both items for either version of a query was not through the PECL package--it was through the mongo shell directly.